# salesforce_reporting python unable to filter results

Tags: python

I am using the salesforce_reporting module available from

https://github.com/cghall/salesforce-reporting

```
from salesforce_reporting import Connection, ReportParser

my_sf = Connection(username='abcd@sfdc.com',
                   password='somegibberishdonteventryit', security_token='jdjfkfk030==',
                   api_version='v46.0')

This works and the report has abuot 2000 items in the report List
report = my_sf.get_report(report_id='00O1B000008BjNw',
                          filters=None, 
                          details=True)
```

However if i do

```
my_custom_filter = ['{"value":"1234", "operator": "equals", "column": "CUST_ID"}']
report = my_sf.get_report(report_id='00O1B000008BjNw',
                          filters=my_custom_filter, 
                          details=True)
report
[{'message': 'The request body is either invalid or incomplete.',
  'errorCode': 'JSON_PARSER_ERROR'}]
```

Clearly the filters parameter is not being liked 
what am i doing wrong here any ideas